# How can I stop a DataGridView with a Filter set from moving too far down the list?

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, datagridview, filter

Consider a dataGridView bound to some database. The binding source for the dataGridView has a filter that will only show where the description field is empty.

The idea is that the user will only see records with this value, records that require their attention.  The user will always change that value to something else.

My problem is once they move to the next row through either the enter or tab key, it filters almost after they have moved to the next row, moving its position to the row below where they should be.

Is there a way to control this behavior so that the position doesn't skip to the next row after filtering occurs?  I don't want to do separate fill's on the dataset for this particular question though I am aware that is it a solution.  I would like to know how to control the filtering better, if possible.

*EDIT*

Worth noting that I have not wired up any events to the datagridview, this is out-of-the-box behavior of dragging the control onto the form, hooking up a binding source to it from a dataset, and filling the dataset on the form_load event.

*EDIT*

Example of current behavior - (C) represents cursor location

User keys a name in row #2 and sets the status to TRUE

```
R1 - John Doe     FALSE
R2 - Jane Doe     TRUE (C)
R3 - Rob  Doe     FALSE
R4 - Joe  Doe     FALSE
```

User presses return (or tab, it doesn't matter which, for this example its enter...)

```
R1 - John Doe     FALSE 
R3 - Rob  Doe     FALSE 
R4 - Joe  Doe     FALSE (C)
```

The current selected row is now row 4 where it really should be row 3.  If I had not changed the value from false to true for R2, it wouldn't have filtered and would have correctly moved me to row 3

*EDIT*

Resurrecting this from the dead as I have not received a suitable solution to this problem.  Anybody out there have a creative idea? ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem with `DataGridView` a while ago.
I wanted to change the behavior of the Enter key to move the selected rows up instead of down. Here is what I did, I hope it helps you. I made a control that inherits DataGridView, and overrided `ProcessCmdKey` and did the changes in it. In your case what you want to do is:

```
public partial class MyDataGridView : DataGridView
{
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == Keys.Tab || keyData == Keys.Enter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

This will stop the gridView from moving to next row when pressing Enter or Tab. I hope it works for you, if it does not please say what is the problem.

Comment: This certainly stops the user from moving anywhere, period which is not really what I'm looking for, they still need to tab to the next row.  I would like the filter to kick in and put the user back in the row that they should be in rather than an additional row down from where it should have put them.  This is important to note because the row will not always filter, only if certain criteria is changed.  There are a few reasons why they would leave the values as-is

Comment: you can modify this code to do what ever you want just before return true write code to select the cell you need. just make the cell you want the cursor to go selected like this DataGridView.Row[index].Cells[index].Selected = true; if explain what acctualy you want to do i can write you something like example

Comment: The problem is that in order for the filter to take effect you must leave that row.  If the user can't progress it will never filter that record out.  It needs to filter that record and put the cursor to the next record and unfortunately, it's moving the cursor down two records once the filter has completed its update